# Cannot get parameter when sending a post request

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'm using attribute routing. I cannot get parameters from HTTP body, can anyone please tell what's wrong here. My ConnectionID Class has a property called CValue.

```
$('#btn').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:49289/api/Resolver/StartRun",
        data: { "CValue": connectionID },
        success: success,
        dataType: "json"
    });
});



[Route("api/Resolver/StartRun")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<string> GetStatus([FromBody]ConnectionID connectionID)
{
}
```

Comment: What does the server's response to the request say?

Comment: @wahwahwah http code 200, all is good, just cannot get the parameter value...

Comment: Does your `ConnectionID` model have a property called `CValue`?

Comment: @wahwahwah yes, it has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the path which will require CORS, if you change your path to be relative:

```
url: "/api/Resolver/StartRun",
```

It should run no problem, here is the simple examples I used to demo this.

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/api/Resolver/StartRun",
            data: { "CValue": "123" },
            success: new function(){},
            dataType: "json
           });
</script>
```

**Controller**

```
    [Route("api/Resolver/StartRun")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<string> GetStatus([FromBody]ConnectionID connectionID)
    {
        return "test";
    }
```

**Class**

```
public class ConnectionID
{
    public string CValue { get; set; }
}
```

**Screen shot**

[image]

You will have to take my word for the parameter being populated, on a mac and I can't remember how to take a print screen (used snipping tool) but if you run it with the above you will see. :)

Comment: I have enabled the Cors option by saying app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll).   From what I have read and your demo, I really feel the code is correct. Maybe I used the wrong version routingattribute assembly... Thank you very much.

Comment: @user3033715 No problem, I would try it with a clean solution. Just the default from out of the box worked for me.